# Read Excel (LibreOffice) using ADODB Connection in UFT

Tags: excel, libreoffice, hp-uft

I have been using Microsoft excel with UFT and we used excel as a database and fetched values from it using ADODB connection from UFT. Below is the connection string we used.

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=" & strExcelPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;"&IMEX&""";"
```

My doubt is, we are migrating to the LibreOffice and I need to know if I can use similar way to fetch values from excel using ADODB.
I tried similar connection string but I got an error saying  "Unrecognized database format".

```
 "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strExcelPath
```

Is it that LibreOffice excel do not have a feature to be used as a database or am I using the incorrect way to fetch the values?